# comparing characters (letters) on c

Tags: c

Im making this program to compare letters. The goal of this is to make a hangman game. But i cant make the letter comparison to work

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int c=0,x;
char a[50],b[50],n[50],j,h;
char a1[50],b1[50],y;
main()
{
    printf("Player 1:enter a word\n");
    gets(n);
    x=strlen(n);
    printf("%d letters\n",x);

    puts("now enter the word letter by letter");
    do
    {
        gets(a);
        strcat(b,a);
        c++;

    }
    while(c!=x);
    printf("%s",b);
    getch();
    system("cls");

    c=0;

    puts("Player 2:try to guess the word letter by letter");
    do
    {
        gets(a1);
        y=strcmp(a,a1);
        printf("%d",y);
        strcat(b1,a1);
        c++;
    }
    while(c!=x);

    printf("%s",b1);


    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

im having problems in particular with the player 2 section. This is not supposed to be the whole comparing letters program; this is just comparing letters to whatever is in the player 1 section (but it keeps trowing 1 and -1 and have no idea how to fix this).

Im sure with a little bit more programming knowledge, i should be able to fix this, but im a beginner trying to learn almost on my own. Any tip would be extremely helpful :)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it keeps trowing 1 and -1". Which part of the code are you specifically referring to? And clarify what you mean by "throw" as that is not a common C term.

Comment: sorry if my terms are not the correct ones (self taught): y=strcmp(a,a1);
        printf("%d",y);

Comment: `while (c!=x)` is probably wrong, unless you want an infinite loop.

Comment: put this at the top: `memset(a, 0, 50);` same for b, a1, b1

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I don't think that's needed. Global variables are always zeroed.

Comment: @AlanAu, looks like you're right. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Zugoldragon It's really not clear what you are trying to do at all in your code. A few comments throughout your code would help in that regard. I think any answer would need to do a full re-write of your code as it's just too unclear. For example, why is  the first argument to `strcmp` set to `a`? `a` is the last letter that was read for player 1. It's not clear what that is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Zugoldragon And why does player 1 need to enter the word twice - once in full and once one letter at a time? That doesn't resemble any game of hang man that I've played before. What exactly is the point of that?

Comment: sorry if my terms are not the correct ones (self taught): y=strcmp(a,a1);
        printf("%d",y); this part is what i was talking about. in this part im comparing a and a1: if they're equal they should read 0

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `a` stores a temporary value of Player1's input, so if Player1 input "abide", the result will be `a = "e"` after Plyaer1's loop. In Player2's loop, you always compare "e" with user's input.

A solution may be that compares the first character instead of using `strcmp`

```
y = b[c] - a1[0];
```